# Int numbers appearing as 0x00000000

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

For some reason all my numbers appear as 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000002 when I hover over them.

Is this some kind of setting I've accidently turned on or does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: `Hex` button on the toolbar?

Comment: What you mean you can't count in hex?  My god I ditched decimal years ago!

Comment: @Andras Zoltan I usually count in square roots when I'm bored

Comment: @iKode I tried doing it in Logs once - but I stopped after I made a set of shelves that were wider than the house.  

Should have realised when it took a low-loader to deliver the wood.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hover over the variable -> right click -> uncheck hexadecimal display

Actually, Roman R. comment is even better, never saw it before :)

Comment: Thanks, save my day!.